# Error while make Build osm2pgrouting on openSUSE 13.2

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, postgis-1.5, osm2pgrouting

i am getting the error while make

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lpq
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [osm2pgrouting] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/osm2pgrouting.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What i need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a package manager for your OS, install one of:

- `libpq-dev` for Debian, Ubuntu and friends, or
- `libpq-devel` for RHEL, CentOS and friends.

See also ["Building libpq Programs"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-build.html).